# What is the crlcache keychain and why do I have so many of them?

Tags: macos, command-line, keychain, script

I run the keychain command-line app that allows me to fast-sleep my Mac or quickly lock a keychain. However, it seems to think that I have many crlcache keychains:

[image]

When I search for crlcache on my system, the only file I find is:

```
[Dance ~ 11:09:48]$ locate crlcache
/private/var/db/crls/crlcache.db
[Dance ~ 11:09:56]$ ls -l /private/var/db/crls/crlcache.db
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  138216 Feb 16 18:18 /private/var/db/crls/crlcache.db
[Dance ~ 11:10:09]$ ls -l /private/var/db/crls/
total 385868
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  156633946 Feb 15 13:51 00EB0CCCF4716CBA4623A3D52F98D43DF630A91D.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       3193 Feb 15 13:51 00EB0CCCF4716CBA4623A3D52F98D43DF630A91D.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   64915907 Feb 15 13:53 00EB0CCCF4716CBA4623A3D52F98D43DF630A91D.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Feb 15 13:52 00EB0CCCF4716CBA4623A3D52F98D43DF630A91D.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     349557 Jan 17 10:14 02B8F639D67DE595D5B990C7365B227EEF2147CA.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       4127 Jan 17 10:14 02B8F639D67DE595D5B990C7365B227EEF2147CA.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     245330 Jan 17 10:14 02B8F639D67DE595D5B990C7365B227EEF2147CA.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Jan 17 10:14 02B8F639D67DE595D5B990C7365B227EEF2147CA.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   17010447 Jan 17 09:41 048F69989050838246F359F3747684F066F55F89.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       3160 Jan 17 09:41 048F69989050838246F359F3747684F066F55F89.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    5412268 Jan 17 09:41 048F69989050838246F359F3747684F066F55F89.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Jan 17 09:41 048F69989050838246F359F3747684F066F55F89.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   22426866 Jan 17 09:15 33AF9B2AF9EE55453E70F230CEE6F1B088A11E53.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       3152 Jan 17 09:15 33AF9B2AF9EE55453E70F230CEE6F1B088A11E53.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    7095036 Jan 17 09:15 33AF9B2AF9EE55453E70F230CEE6F1B088A11E53.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Jan 17 09:15 33AF9B2AF9EE55453E70F230CEE6F1B088A11E53.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     150251 Feb 17 21:44 6D42DDADB61DE578D7E8AE1F55B847E7D2211227.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       1952 Feb 17 21:44 6D42DDADB61DE578D7E8AE1F55B847E7D2211227.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel          0 Feb 17 21:44 6D42DDADB61DE578D7E8AE1F55B847E7D2211227.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Feb 17 21:44 6D42DDADB61DE578D7E8AE1F55B847E7D2211227.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   22163480 Feb  2 17:02 725FB81052E5B7712EBEFB4795675251CCC3BC52.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       3160 Feb  2 17:02 725FB81052E5B7712EBEFB4795675251CCC3BC52.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    7014670 Feb  2 17:02 725FB81052E5B7712EBEFB4795675251CCC3BC52.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Feb  2 17:02 725FB81052E5B7712EBEFB4795675251CCC3BC52.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     146048 Jan 17 10:48 883F19386296795F3147EBE82296B2D27A52B071.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       2061 Jan 17 10:48 883F19386296795F3147EBE82296B2D27A52B071.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     128662 Jan 17 10:48 883F19386296795F3147EBE82296B2D27A52B071.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Jan 17 10:48 883F19386296795F3147EBE82296B2D27A52B071.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   23249559 Jan 17 09:19 B17D3E16D3A0F9C7F88CC316029C5AC00C505536.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       3160 Jan 17 09:19 B17D3E16D3A0F9C7F88CC316029C5AC00C505536.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    7397440 Jan 17 09:19 B17D3E16D3A0F9C7F88CC316029C5AC00C505536.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Jan 17 09:19 B17D3E16D3A0F9C7F88CC316029C5AC00C505536.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    1120674 Feb 13 22:52 C7F09F48274C5E3AA39F26B6331F4BADB6FB7C26.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       3205 Feb 13 22:52 C7F09F48274C5E3AA39F26B6331F4BADB6FB7C26.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    1040852 Feb 13 22:52 C7F09F48274C5E3AA39F26B6331F4BADB6FB7C26.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Feb 13 22:52 C7F09F48274C5E3AA39F26B6331F4BADB6FB7C26.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   18404099 Feb 14 19:50 EF60748B11A1CBB3DA17B561326A3C2A03A6436A.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       6477 Feb 14 19:50 EF60748B11A1CBB3DA17B561326A3C2A03A6436A.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    7089092 Feb 14 19:50 EF60748B11A1CBB3DA17B561326A3C2A03A6436A.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Feb 14 19:50 EF60748B11A1CBB3DA17B561326A3C2A03A6436A.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   24860240 Jan 17 09:13 F6353240A71E06E460868101176CBF82936A274B.crl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       3160 Jan 17 09:13 F6353240A71E06E460868101176CBF82936A274B.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    7868651 Jan 17 09:13 F6353240A71E06E460868101176CBF82936A274B.revoked
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         25 Jan 17 09:13 F6353240A71E06E460868101176CBF82936A274B.update
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     138216 Feb 16 18:18 crlcache.db
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     118328 Feb 18 10:45 ocspcache.db
[Dance ~ 11:10:11]$
```

Here are my keychains:

```
[Dance ~ 11:13:50]$ ls -l /Library/Keychains
total 196
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  125412 Feb 14 17:17 System.keychain
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel   20460 Oct 16  2014 System.keychain-orig
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel   51440 Nov 15 00:28 apsd.keychain
[Dance ~ 11:13:54]$ ls -l Library/Keychains/
total 5680
drwx------  7 user  staff      238 Jan 28 08:20 15F335F0-18E6-5BBF-8294-C47E82A0EE22/
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    20460 Jan 18  2014 Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  2809980 Feb 18 11:05 login.keychain
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  1088800 Feb  1  2014 login.keychain.sb-ea2853d9-bzChLx
-rw-------  1 user  staff  1891832 Feb 18 10:40 metadata.keychain
[Dance ~ 11:14:00]$ ls -l Library/Keychains/15F335F0-18E6-5BBF-8294-C47E82A0EE22/
total 3200
-rw-------  1 user  staff       47 Oct  7 12:14 accountStatus.plist
-rw-------  1 user  staff   561152 Feb 17 18:01 keychain-2.db
-rw-------  1 user  staff    32768 Feb 17 21:44 keychain-2.db-shm
-rw-------  1 user  staff  2673912 Feb 18 11:12 keychain-2.db-wal
-rw-------  1 user  staff     1396 Oct 17  2014 user.kb
[Dance ~ 11:14:07]$
```

In the Keychain app,  I only see a single keychain:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Do each of the crlcache keychains show up as entries in the Keychain Access app or are they just in the menu item? Similarly, do they show up when you type `security list-keychains` from the command line?

Comment: I only have a single crcache.db in the keychain.

Comment: Grrr.. You've clearly found a weakness in the code - without knowing how to provoke a system into that state, I'm at a loss how to debug it further. +1 from me so I hope this gets more eyes and some other ideas.

Comment: I've gotten much more feedback on reports the past 48 months. I don't know if others giving up lets mine get more attention or if I'm getting better at reporting things they care to address. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 1):

CRL typically stands for [certificate revocation list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list) but something is really amiss on this system that might need Apple engineering assistance to remedy. The reason I say that is your listings all look appropriate and you don't have an explicit keychain for each entry in the UI.

Without analyzing your usage of the script, the logical conclusion I would make is that these are artifacts or direct results of your scripting.

One thing you could try is disabling both OCSP and CRL temporarily and see if the count of rogue keychains remains stable. In theory - it's always best to check for revoked certificates, but in practice, you might not be at much risk if you do so for a short period of time or even in general.

Another thing would be to look at the open files for the process to see if you can locate keychain files outside the normal ~/Library/Keychains and /Library/Keychains locations on the filesystem. If they are hidden in /private or worse - kept in RAM and exposed like a file, you might have a hard time tracking them down without placing that program in a debugger like Instruments.

Comment: What do you mean, "the script?" I'm not running any scripts. How could keychains be elsewhere on the system and show up in the system keychain?

Comment: I assumed you scripted your use of **keychain command-line app that allows me to fast-sleep my Mac or quickly lock a keychain** and the "other keychains" is speculation. Either there's a data corruption issue in the code or there are other keychains - either would explain what you're seeing and what you're reporting, @vy32

Comment: I agree that there may be a data corruption issue. But what specifically would I script?